# Android: Detect if PVPlayer or AwesomePlayer?

Tags: android

How can I detect if a device is equipped with the "PVPlayer" components or "AwesomePlayer" components?

I noticed that the Droid X, despite being on Android 2.2, still uses the PVPlayer component rather than AwesomePlayer. in other words, the Droid X has difficulty playing certain types of media.

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look into the PackageManager class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/70/