# What is AwesomePlayer in android?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I was looking at the logs on my device for one my apps, however, I see a lot of logs generated by AwesomePlayer. Is this the default media player used by apps that plays videos. I have no idea why this is coming up. Is this a default android app doing this? Below is a sample to see what it looks like.

Device: Android 3.2 Galaxy 10.1

Any hint will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:08.660: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 440560000
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getTimeForOffset
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): notifyListener_l
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedDuration_l
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:08.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): postBufferingEvent_l
02-09 02:23:09.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): isPlaying
02-09 02:23:09.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:09.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:09.080: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 440960000
02-09 02:23:09.590: E/AwesomePlayer(240): on video lag update
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): onBufferingUpdate
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): notifyListener_l
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedDuration_l
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:09.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): postBufferingEvent_l
02-09 02:23:10.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): isPlaying
02-09 02:23:10.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:10.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:10.080: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 441960000
02-09 02:23:10.590: E/AwesomePlayer(240): on video lag update
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): onBufferingUpdate
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedAmountPercentage
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:10.660: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 442560000
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getTimeForOffset
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): notifyListener_l
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedDuration_l
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:10.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): postBufferingEvent_l
02-09 02:23:11.010: D/HierarchicalStateMachine(305): handleMessage: E msg.what=83
02-09 02:23:11.010: D/HierarchicalStateMachine(305): processMsg: ConnectedState
02-09 02:23:11.010: D/WifiStateMachine(305): ConnectedState{ what=83 when=-3ms arg1=4 }
02-09 02:23:11.020: D/HierarchicalStateMachine(305): handleMessage: X
02-09 02:23:11.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): isPlaying
02-09 02:23:11.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:11.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:11.080: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 442960000
02-09 02:23:11.590: E/AwesomePlayer(240): on video lag update
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): onBufferingUpdate
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): notifyListener_l
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedDuration_l
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:11.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): postBufferingEvent_l
02-09 02:23:12.050: D/SntpClient(305): request time failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Try again
02-09 02:23:12.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): isPlaying
02-09 02:23:12.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:12.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:12.080: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 443960000
02-09 02:23:12.590: E/AwesomePlayer(240): on video lag update
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): onBufferingUpdate
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedAmountPercentage
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:12.660: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 444520000
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getTimeForOffset
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): notifyListener_l
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getCachedDuration_l
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getBitrate
02-09 02:23:12.660: D/AwesomePlayer(240): postBufferingEvent_l
02-09 02:23:13.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): isPlaying
02-09 02:23:13.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): getPosition
02-09 02:23:13.080: D/AwesomePlayer(240): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
02-09 02:23:13.080: I/AwesomePlayer(240): position is : 444960000
```

Comment: This is not a programming question. A better place for your question would be http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: When you say one of your applications is it one that you wrote. If it is then this question may be ablet o stay here if you elaborate.

Comment: I disagree with the close-as-off-topic decision. I just gave a bug report to a developer about a video failing to play in their app; they used standard Android SDK video playback functionality but it was replaced by AwesomePlayer on my phone. This was a total surprise to them, and this question/answer is helping to guide to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The awesome player is something that comes equipped on some devices (Mostly newer ones). There is apparently an alternate according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919258/android-detect-if-pvplayer-or-awesomeplayer).

The Awesomeplayer succeeeded the PVPlayer compenents that were in older devices.

From this it would seem something regarding the way you are trying to play your video is not set up properly.

***Side Note:***

It is also the name of an application on the market.

[Awesome Media Player (Paid)](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/music_and_audio/awesome-media-player_lmjt.html)

[Awesome Media Player Lite (Free)](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/media_and_video/awesome-media-player-lite_hvem.html)