# mkv video jitters on ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-videoview

I try to use the class `Videoview` to play a MKV file on my Archos tablet.
The layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/intro_surface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    VideoView l_tv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.intro_surface);
    Uri l_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.intro_mkv);
    l_tv.setVideoURI(p_uri) ;
    l_tv.start();
}
```

The video plays but jitters whereas it plays correctly when I use the external video player.
I activated the hardware acceleration in the manifest.
I saw some logs related to `AwesomePlayer` but I could not find this player on the tablet.

`Seek tolerance hit mTimeSourceDeltaUs=-593897 seek_tolerance=520500`.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230864/what-is-awesomeplayer-in-android) about awesomeplayer but it did not help.

Is there a fix to this problem ?

Comment: `AwesomePlayer` is the standard gooogle video player of Android. If that one can't play your .mkv fluid then playing the video via the google video player (via the gallery) should jitter as well and there is nothing you can do besides implementing you own video player like Archos did

Comment: Ok. I will dive into ffmpeg when I have time...